# How to remove or disallow JavaScript smooth scrolling on foreign webpage?

Tags: javascript

I'm browsing webpage [www.templatemonster.com](http://www.templatemonster.com) and the smooth (animated) scrolling is **really annoying** for me. It's slowing down the browsing for me. I assume it's doing by some javascript.

Other webpages are scrolling fast without *"low FPS"* but the above one is really slow.

I use Win7 + Chrome. It's the same in other browsers (IE, FF, Opera,...).

Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: You can disable javascript, but i bet site wont work. Searching for js file? they have compiled, minified js [here](http://static.templatemonster.com/js/compiled.application.en.js?73edf7c) so it could be hard to find appropiate line

Comment: The scroll event handler appears to be on line 6 of the source. Only way you'd be able to get rid of it is by turning off JavaScript or replacing `document.addEventListener`? (not entirely sure which node it's on) before it's used. You might be able to achieve this with a userscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
getEventListeners(window).wheel[0].remove()
```

It needs to be run in console after page load. Working in Google Chrome.